# Subsetting or filtering of data as per dynamic user input

Tags: dynamic, dataframe, shiny, dplyr

I like to filter data as per dynamic user input. Below mentioned sample code is executable, however, currently, it does not have the logic to filter the data. Therefore, the table does not change irrespective of selection of any variables.
 The code has mainly three components: 1. First few lines of code creates a data frame of which information can be used in creating controls widgets on the fly; 2. `ui`  code; 3. `server` currently has logic to create control widgets on the fly, and I need to figure out how to use information from dynamically created control widgets and filter data (which is used for different purposes). I'm unable to figure out how to track the number of variable and filtering as per their range. Greatly appreciate suggestions.

```
## Create a data frame of which information is used in creating (dynamical) control widgets
varnames <- names(iris[,1:4]) # names
varinit <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,median) # initival value used in slider
varmin <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,min) # min.
varmax <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,max) # max. 

## dataframe
vardf <- data.frame(varnames,varmin,varmax,varinit)

ui <- fluidPage(
   checkboxGroupInput("ConditioningVariables", "Conditioning variables (choose one or more):",
                      varnames,inline = TRUE),
uiOutput("ControlWidgetsofConditioningVariables"),
   tableOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$ControlWidgetsofConditioningVariables <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$ConditioningVariables)){
         return() 
      } else {
         selvarnames = sort(input$ConditioningVariables)
         selpos = sapply(selvarnames,function(x) which(varnames==x))
         # create a taglist of dynamic widgets
         ListofDynamicWidgets <- lapply(selpos, function(x){sliderInput(as.character(vardf[x,1]),
                                                          as.character(vardf[x,1]),
                                                          vardf[x,2],vardf[x,3],
                                                          vardf[x,4],.1)})
         do.call(tagList, ListofDynamicWidgets)
      }
   })
   ## filter data as per selected variables and their range
   ## this is where I'm kind of struck, I think I need to track number of variables (is list good idea?)
   ## and filter as per selected range of a specific variable
   newdata <- reactive({
      subset(iris)
   })
   output$data <- renderTable({ newdata() })
   }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach (note that I slightly modified the code to generate the widgets).  The main idea is to generate a named list of the range vectors (`conds`), convert the ranges into a list of character strings that represent the filtering conditions (`subs`), collapse them into one long string of conditions, and use that as the subsetting argument for `filter_()`.

```
library(dplyr)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  allControls <- lapply(setNames(varnames, varnames), function(x) {
    sliderInput(x, x, varmin[x], varmax[x], c(varmin[x], varinit[x]), 
      round = -2)
  })
  output$ControlWidgetsofConditioningVariables <- renderUI({    
    if (is.null(input$ConditioningVariables)){
      return() 
    } else {
      allControls[input$ConditioningVariables]
    }
  })
  ## filter data as per selected variables and their range
  newdata <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$ConditioningVariables)) {
      cond_names <- input$ConditioningVariables
      conds <- lapply(setNames(cond_names, cond_names), function(x) input[[x]])
      subs <- mapply(function(name, range){
        if (!is.null(range))
          sprintf("%1$s >= %2$f & %1$s <= %3$f", name, range[1], range[2])
      }, names(conds), conds)
      subs <- subs[!sapply(subs, is.null)]
      if (length(subs) > 0)
        filter_(iris, paste0(subs, collapse = " & "))    
      } else {
        iris
      }
    })
  output$data <- renderTable({ newdata() })
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Good to know that it is not must to use `tagList` to generate widgets. Filtering data - very clever use of commands that appear to be simple. Awesome.

Comment: Is there any command that directly gives row positions (or numbers) meeting the criterion? Typically, I save all row numbers in a separate column and figure out row numbers from that specific column.

Comment: You might want to open a new question for this (or check if there's an existing question on SO); but here's an example of one approach: `with(iris, which(eval(parse(text = "Sepal.Length >= 5 & Sepal.Length <= 6"))))`

Comment: @ Weihuang Wong  Request you to provide information on the following: 1. I understand that `input[[x]]` extracts element `x` range, but not sure how to call this function outside server.R. I tried data filtering algorithm as a separate function in the global.R, and when I ran it gave me an error _object `input` not found_. 2. Unable to this particular line `subs <- subs[!sapply(subs, is.null)]`. Thanks.

Comment: Please open a new question that includes a description of your problem with a minimal reproducible example. This way you'll be able to get help from other people as well.